# GRE Encapsulation and Multicast

Tags: vpn, cisco, routing, gre

How does GRE Encapsulation actually send multicast traffic? My CISCO textbook tells me that the multicast packet is carried inside a unicast packet.

My understanding is:

Multicast packet, say for RIP, has address 224.0.0.9. GRE takes that, wraps it in a unicast packet headed for the host you are tunneling it with; it reaches the recieving-host, is de-capsulated and propagated throughout the recieving-hosts network.

Is that right more or less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is more or less correct, at least in principle. You do need to configure multicast routing, though.